# How to override a stream's primary key properties or incremental replication key in Meltano?

Tags: meltano, singer-io

There are times when we want to override a stream's key properties (primary key) or it's incremental replication key. What's the best way to do this in Meltano?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your Meltano yaml file, you can add a `table-key-properties` and/or `replication-key` override using the `metadata` extra config.

Docs reference: https://docs.meltano.com/concepts/plugins#metadata-extra

Example yaml code:

```yaml
extractors:
- name: tap-postgres
  metadata:
    some_stream_id:
      table-key-properties: [id]
      replication-key: created_at
      replication-method: INCREMENTAL
```

This example sets the primary key to `id` and the replication key to `created_at`.

#### Update regarding wildcards (2022-03-30)

Per @visch's comment, wildcards can also be used in stream names to match multiple streams at once. Such as in these example:

```yaml
extractors:
- name: tap-postgres
  metadata:
    "*":
      # set all streams to "full table" mode
      replication-method: FULL_TABLE
```

And:

```yaml
extractors:
- name: tap-postgres
  metadata:
    "*":
      # ignore primary keys for all streams
      table-key-properties: []
```

Comment: For testing and just starting with singer or a new tap I like to use

    metadata:
      '*':
        replication-method: FULL_TABLE


As that way I can just see the data and figure out the replication stuff later. Realized the comment is hard to read, https://gitlab.com/vischous/oracle2mssql/-/blob/master/oracle2mssql/meltano.yml#L46-48 is much easier

Comment: Thanks, @visch! I've updated my answer using this example.

Comment: @aaronsteers can you please correct your answer?

Apparently, it was renamed from `key-properties` to `table-key-properties`. At least in version 2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

After having followed @visch suggestion by using

```
  metadata:
    "*":
      replication-method: FULL_TABLE
```

from the logs (when running Meltano in debug mode with `--log-level=debug`) in discovery mode you should see something like:

```
metadata node for tap_stream_id 'mydb-mytable'
```

From the above you can get the correct collection name and then structure the `meltano.yml` accordingly:

```
extractors:
- name: tap-postgres

  select:
  - mydb-mytable.*

  metadata:
    mydb-mytable:
      table-key-properties: [id]
      replication-method: INCREMENTAL
      replication-key: created_at
```

In particular it was very important for me to add the `select` field as otherwise I was getting this error message:

```
ERROR message=Invalid replication method None! 
replication method needs to be either FULL_TABLE or INCREMENTAL
```